# Каталог "." занимает 11Gb. Можно ли удалить? Как посмотреть, что внутри?

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, vps

Каталог "." занимает 11Gb. Можно ли удалить? Как посмотреть, что внутри?
При этом объем всего диска 19Gb. Возможно "." означает весь родительский каталог, но тогда возникает вопрос "куда делось еще 8Gb ?"

*Еще детали, посл перезагрузки освободилось 7.3 Гб. Как не перезагружать систему и освобождать это место?*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас первой же строчкой - `8.4G /root`. Не эти ли 8 гигов вы потеряли?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`.`** – текущий каталог. Тот, в котором Вы находитесь в данный момент.

Так как в данный момент Вы находитесь в корневом каталоге **`/`**, то размер каталога **`.`** – это суммарный размер всех вложений корневого каталога, то есть, по сути, размер всех файлов на Вашем компьютере.

P.S. Почитайте про относительные пути и в принципе все пути в Linux. Там ещё много интересного, кроме **`.`**. Например, [здесь](https://losst.ru/put-k-fajlu-v-linux).

Comment: Добавил скриншот с размером всего диска. Могли бы Вы подсказать, куда девается еще 8 гигабайт?

Comment: Еще детали, посл перезагрузки освободилось 7.3 Гб. Как не перезагружать систему и освобождать это место?

Comment: @ЕвгенийАрхипов Никуда. Они просто пока не заняты. Это пустое пространство, ждущее, пока в него что-нибудь запишут.

Comment: @ЕвгенийАрхипов а насчёт перезагрузки – задавайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: ок, спасибо большое!